# Efficiently track Windows processes (loading and unloading)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, performance, process

I am struggling to find a way to dynamically keep track of windows processes as they spawn (load) and die (unload) using as little of the CPU as possible.

My current solution uses the `K32EnumProcesses` to get all running pids (Process Ids) and basic set operations to deduce the dead and spawned pids.

```
class Procs:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_all_processes(self):
        pProcessIds = (c_ulong * 4096)()
        pBytesReturned = c_ulong()
        hModule = c_ulong()
        count = c_ulong()
        kernel32.K32EnumProcesses(byref(pProcessIds), sizeof(pProcessIds), byref(pBytesReturned))
        nReturned = pBytesReturned.value/sizeof(c_ulong())
        for pid in [i for i in pProcessIds][:int(nReturned)]:
            yield int(pid)

    def find_dead(self, prev_pids, curr_pids):
        return prev_pids - curr_pids

    def find_live(self, prev_pids, curr_pids):
        return curr_pids - prev_pids

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc_obj = Procs()
    prev_procs = set()
    while True:
        curr_procs = set(proc_obj.get_all_processes())
        dead = proc_obj.find_dead(prev_procs, curr_procs)
        live = proc_obj.find_live(prev_procs, curr_procs)
        [print(f'died: {d}') for d in dead]
        [print(f'live: {l}') for l in live]
        dead = None
        live = None
        prev_procs = curr_procs
```

The problem with this solution is that it uses around 50% of the CPU.

[CPU and memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsrfA.png) (image)

I've tried piping to cmd tasklist and parsing the output but it isn't any better.

I don't know if there is a way to get windows to notify the program when a new process has loaded or if I might have to resort to a driver.

To give a bit of context this solution will be part of a program which will scan processes as they load for malware, and will run on older systems which don't have much processing power or available memory.

Comment: How often do you need to access this information?  If you need to track the processes ten times per second, for example, you can simply insert `time.sleep(0.1)` after your `while True:` statement.  You are using CPU resources because your while True loop runs all the time.

Comment: Use [wmi](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi) to create two [`Win32_Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372)  watchers for "creation" and "deletion" events, polling them sequentially in a loop, e.g. `for watcher in itertools.cycle([process_creation_watcher, process_deletion_watcher])`. Call the watcher with a timeout such as `process = watcher(timeout_ms=50)` and ignore the `wmi.x_wmi_timed_out` exception. The object has `event_type` and `timestamp` attributes in addition to `Win32_Process` methods (e.g. `Terminate`) and properties (e.g. `Name`, `ProcessId`).